# Wallpaper changes automatically

Tags: 12.04

I am working in a company. Here the IT team is changing my wallpaper automatically. 
I went to /usr/share/backgrounds and found the current wallpaper there with name say abc.jpg and permission of 755. 
I changed the Name of this file to abc.jpg_bk and placed my desired wallpaper with the same name abc.jpg and permission as 644 and restarted my system.

After Restart I see again abc.jpg is replaced with the same company wallpaper and permission 755. i.e. now i have abc.jpg_bk and abc.jpg having same wallpaper.

This is question is out of curiosity as how this is happening. Which Script is downloading the wallpaper from the server and replacing /usr/share/backgrounds/abc.jpg on every startup/shutdown or boot.

And how I can make this stop.

I am Using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

> This is question is out of curiosity as how this is happening. Which Script is downloading the wallpaper from the server and replacing /usr/share/backgrounds/abc.jpg on every startup/shutdown or boot.

Impossible for us to answer. The script name is decided by your IT department and is not a "generic" name.

There are a lot of methods on how to do this. The 2 main methods are ...

- crontab
- /etc/crontab

Both can hold a command to do something on `@reboot` where a script can be called to copy that background over to your system. The 1st one is a file per user. So they could have made that with a "root" or a "sudo" account.

```
crontab -l
```

will show your user `crontab`. It is not possible for you to view others unless you know the password for that account. The 2nd is probably readable by anyone (`more /etc/crontab`) but editing requires "sudo" permissions.

But it is also entirely possible that the file is copied over to your system when you boot from a daemon. Where this daemon does a call ("ssh", "ftp") to a central server and retrieves the background from there.

> And how I can make this stop.

You need to ask your IT department.

Comment: I know this was generic.. I was not looking for exact ans. I was looking for what are the ways in Ubuntu by which this can be achieved. I had already checked the Crontab and nothing was present over there.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make this file immutable:

```
chattr +i /usr/share/backgrounds/abc.jpg
```

When you do this, nobody will be able to overwrite it, even scripts running as root.